# excluding an exact phrase in regular expression

Tags: regex, phrase

this is a part of my code to find "1" in the p,span,a and some other tags, also between "{changenumber}" and "{/changenumber}" anywhere and then replace it with "2":

code for find:

```
(((<(p|span|a|li|ul|br|/br|tr|td)[^>]*>)|(\{changenumber\}))[^<|(\{/changenumber\})]*)1(.*(<|(\{/changenumber\})))
```

and code for replace:

```
\12\7
```

but there is a problem it exclude in `[^<|(\{/changenumber\})]` all the characters of this phrase: `"{","c","h","a"`,etc

I try `\b\{/changenumber\}\b` and `(?!...)` but I can't!

How it can exclude the exact phrase "`{changenumber}`"?!

---

In a simpler way:

when we write [^abc]+ it excludes "a" and "b" and "c" but what's the way if we want it to exclude the exact "abc"?!

[^(abc)]+ doesn't work

[^\babc\b]+ doesn't work

(?!abc) doesn't work

(?!\babc\b) deosn't work

...

---

Its language is English

I use regex because it's the way to replace in the rereplacer component in joomla

No way?!!!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Also, why are you parsing html with regexes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

> when we write [^abc]+ it excludes "a" and "b" and "c" but what's the
>   way if we want it to exclude the exact "abc"?!
>
> [^(abc)]+ doesn't work
>
> [^\babc\b]+ doesn't work
>
> (?!abc) doesn't work

That's false; negative lookahead works; if it seems to do not, the usage is at fault.

> but there is a problem: it excludes in `[^<|(\{/changenumber\})]` all the
>   characters of this phrase — "{", "c", "h", "a", etc.

Instead of

```
[^<|(\{/changenumber\})]
```

write

```
((?!\{/changenumber\})[^<])
```

— i. e., place the lookahead in front of the negated set.

Besides, you should make the `.*` non-greedy by replacing it with `.*?`.